# Edit Website Bindings - SSL cert list is empty

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-10

I setup my development system for a customer in a vm.  I had to create a cert for localhost.  they tell me that their app will not run on the webdev server but on iis only in visual studio.  the other day, I setup a certificate in windows11.  I set it as a trusted cert.  I went to the bindings in the iis manager, selected the cert from the dropdown, and it all worked.  I did this the other day, and it all worked perfectly.  I jumped up into it last night, and everything was working fine.

this morning, I rebooted my vm, and now I get the error message: Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The underlying connection was closed.  An unexpected error occurred on a send.
"Help" doesn't open anything.

I found some posts that lead me to believe that the cert is a problem.  I ran certutil -repairstore my "thumbprint" to which I get an error stating that the repairstore command failed: 0x80090011 NTE_NOT_Found is the general error message and also "Object was not found."

I am lost on where to go to fix this.  any ideas are appreciated.  TIA.

Comment: Since you are on Windows 11, there are too many things that can take effect during reboots and I don't think it is possible to iterate all. You can analyze Windows HTTP API to learn more about the certificates mapped to each site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html That might give you some ideas on what might be wrong.

Comment: Actually, many posts point to certificate issues. According to this official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server?view=vs-2022, have you tried iisreset?  About 0x80090011 error you can refer to: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-0x80090011-error/.

Comment: After another hour or so of futzing with it, I've got it working halfway reliably.  I don't really know what I did that resolved it, but it is currently working.  I've rebooted several times and it is working.